# About tableView bisymmetry

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

My table view on iPhone 7 looks like this:

[image: table view on iPhone 7]

I added new constraints to my table view: top, bottom, left, right 0;
and I checked horizontally in the container, too.

But on my phone (iPhone 7), like the picture shows, my table view doesn't have a vertical symmetry. Is that normal?

I also tested in a tabbed navigation controller, but the results were the same.

I didn't do anything by code. I just made a table view and added contraints...

What is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by vertical symmetry? Do you mean that the cell dividers are indented more on the left side than on the right side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table view separators have a 15 pixel left inset by default. If you want to change that behaviour, set **Separator Insets** to Custom inside the **Attributes inspector** and provide 0 for both values.

[image: Separator Insets settings for table view]

Moreover, your leading and trailing constraints seem to be relative to the superview's margin. Uncheck **Relative to margin** under the constraint's **Size inspector** settings.

[image: Size inspector settings for constraint]

Comment: it works! thanks. Do you know why there is 15 pixel left margin in tableView?

Comment: @정초이 In a long list (what a `UITableView` was generally used for back in the days of early iOS development), a slightly assymetric line could break the monotony a little.

Comment: What property to uncheck? Do you mean unchecking 'Leading' and 'Respect language direction'? or unchecking others ( making 'Leading' and 'Respect language direction' checked only? )

Comment: @정초이 You should uncheck **Relative to margin.** Sorry if that wasn't clear. Updated my answer.